# Passing pointers (matrix) to a function in c

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, dynamic-arrays, dynamic-allocation

I have dynamically created a matrix using calloc in the usual way:

```
int **matrix;
int dim,r;
scanf("%d",&dim);
matrix=(int **)calloc(dim, sizeof(int *));
for(r=0; r<dim; r++)
   {
    matrix[r]=(int *)calloc(dim, sizeof(int));
   }
```

Now if I wanted to create a function to just print the elements of this matrix, I should write something like:

```
void stampmatrix(int **matrix, int dim)
{
int r=0, c=0;
for(r=0; r<dim; r++)
    {
    printf("(");
    for(c=0;c<dim;c++)
        {
        printf(" %d , ",matrix[r][c]);
        }
    printf(")");
     }
}
```

And this works fine.
Now I add this line to the previous function

```
`...`
 matrix[r][c]=1;
 printf(" %d , ",matrix[r][c]);
 ...
```

If i call this function in my main function, 
    stampmatrix(matrix,dim)
once i run the program, the compiler should create a copy of my matrix, fill it with 1, and then print them, and then return to my main function **without changing the actual matrix**. But if I do this and then i check in my main function the values of my matrix elements, they are changed to 1.
In class i was told that if I pass values to a function, the program creates a copy of the values, works with them and then cancel the copy, so I need to pass addresses to a function in order to actually change the contents of my variables in my main function.
Why in this case it doesn't work, and changes my matrix values? It's because I still pass pointers to the function stampmatrix? I really don't understand. Shouldn't the function be something like:

```
void stampfunction(int dim, int ***matrix)
```

Or it's because i used a void function? 
Thanks for the attention!

Comment: The thing that the compiler copies is the *pointer* to the matrix, not the matrix itself.  You will need to make a copy yourself, by hand, including the allocation of memory.

Comment: There is no matrix /aka 2D array( shown, A pointer is not an array. Use the proper way to make things much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, in this program (I assume), all code shares the same heap (memory), and pointers are kind of like signposts, to that heap.

What the method

```
void stampmatrix(int **matrix, int dim)
```

does is like when you give a person a number, `dim`, and physical map to, say, all the signposts to apples in a grid.

So yes, you passed in by value *directions* to the matrix - you gave a person a copy of your apple-signpost-map.

The other thing you did is that `matrix[r][c]` implicitly dereferences the pointer - or, the method is saying to follow the apple-signpost-map directions all the way to point (r, c) in this grid.

So when you say `matrix[r][c] = 1', you're saying to make sure there's only one apple at (r, c) when you leave. That's why the value at matrix[r][c] changed.